# How are transaction between two fragment in BottomNavigationView in Apps like YouTube so smooth?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I am making an application that has `MainActivity` that contains `BottomNavigationView` and `FrameLayout` above it. There are 3 `Fragments` say **Fragment A, B, and C**.

My doubt is, How do I make switching of `Fragments` as quick as YouTube Android application? By saying quick, I mean that, when I am on "Home" tab of Youtube application and I switch to the "Trending" tab and again go back to the "Home" tab, it simply loads "Home" tab within fraction of seconds, as if it just hided the inflated page in background and showed up when selected from `BottomNavigationView`. And also, It inflates the page exactly to the same position where I left.

When I am trying to implement the same in my Application, the `RecyclerView` in **Fragment A** re-inflates if I come back from **Fragment B**.

I am expecting the idea how they do it and in which method they do it (For eg. onStart or onDestroy or onViewCreated)...

Comment: is the content in your recycler view loaded from the internet?

Comment: No... I am using 'SharedPreferanceHelper' to load data... This is also a possible solution I did to avoid lagness...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using viewpager then Increase the viewpager offset limit

```
viewpager.OffscreenPageLimit = 2;
```

Tt's limit is one by default. I hope this may fix your issue.
Thanks

Comment: I am using `FrameLayout` in which I am inflating different `Fragment`.